# Login Issue SDL Web 8.1.1

Tags: web8

We Installed SDL web 8.1.1 on one of the instance , when we login using chrome it's fine but when we access using IE we are getting error . please see attached screen shot , let me know if we need to  enable some settings on IE to fix the issue.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please try this browser [configurations](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Web-v5&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-B4C341FB-2773-43A1-9D2F-48522AC5DA5F&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-B4C341FB-2773-43A1-9D2F-48522AC5DA5F.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-B4C341FB-2773-43A1-9D2F-48522AC5DA5F&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL%20Web-v5%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3Dinternet&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1486078011576&currentQuery=internet&currentScope=)